# how to show page's summary in the home page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I just want to do some thing like that in my home page i want to show grid of my other pages as summary with read more button ... once any body clicks on that read more it will go to that actual single page .... but problem is that i am in index.php and there is other content as well not only these pages summary ... any body kindly help me out of this .....

simply how to show the summary just title and read more link, and all other stuff in indesx.php of wordpress theme.

In the image below red part shows what i want to show for my pages. while in between these boxes other content is also there ....

for reference here is the link for image of what i want [samlpe image of problem](http://capytech.com/services/images/img.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're plenty of options to show different content on your home page.

1.) Use a Page Builder plugin where you manually add your contents via the page editor. If you don't want to touch code that ll be the simplest way.

For example: [Page Builder by SiteOrigin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/)

2.) Create a `front-page.php` template and **widgetize** it with different sidebars e.g. your first marked red area could be a section with 3 spaces (register_sidebar) for widgets. If you added some sidebars to the front-page.php, you ll be able to add content more dynamically via the wigdets admin page.

> functions.php

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'My Custom Widget Area',
    'id' => 'custom'
));
```

> front-page.php

```
<?php
get_header();?>
<div id="page">
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom'  ) :?>
        <div class="widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

---

3.) **Programatically** add your desired area of grids in index.php / page.php and wrap them with a conditional function checking whether your page `is_home()` or `is_front_page()`.

```
<?php if(is_home()): ?>


<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Title1</h2>
        <a href="link to page">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Title2</h2>
        <a href="link to page">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Title3</h2>
        <a href="link to page">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div>


<?php endif; ?>
```

---

Learn more about widgetizing your front-page [here](http://robincornett.com/custom-front-page/)

Answer (score 0):

I have an solution for the simplest problem like this:

In case you just want get datas from the page which you know the title. I think with this code we can easily archive that:

```
function getPageBlockInfo($page_title) {
    $page = get_page_by_title($page_title);

    $arrInfo = array();
    $arrImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' );

    $arrInfo['image_src'] = $arrImg[0];
    $arrInfo['title'] = $page->post_title;
    $arrInfo['link'] = get_permalink($page);
    $arrInfo['summary'] = $page->post_content;

    return $arrInfo;

}
```

For example, getPageBlockInfo('Watch Me Grow');

In your case you just need call 5 times with this function.